# mui datatable Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'download')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables, jsx, mui-datatable

I'm using  `"react": "^17.0.2",` and  `"mui-datatables": "^4.2.2",`

I need to download ( export ) data that is not displayed in the datable .

This is a part of my code  :

```
    [
    // ..... other columns
    {
      label: "Détail IIG",
      name: "reference",
      options: {
        download: false,
        customBodyRender: (value) => {
          if (currentUserId === value.user.id) {
            if (value.calculated) {
              return (
                <Tooltip title="les résultats IIG de votre dossier sont disponibles">
                  <Link
                    className="custom-green-iig-link"
                    to={`/${value.slug}/project/iig`}
                  >
                    <FontAwesomeComponent
                      icon={faEye}
                      size="lg"
                      color="white"
                    />
                  </Link>
                </Tooltip>
              );
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          } else {
            if (value.calculated) {
              return (
                <Tooltip title="Les résultats IIG de ce dossier sont disponibles">
                  <Link
                    className="custom-green-iig-link"
                    to={`/${value.slug}/project/iig`}
                  >
                    <FontAwesomeComponent
                      icon={faEye}
                      size="lg"
                      color="white"
                    />
                  </Link>
                </Tooltip>
              );
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
        },
        setCellHeaderProps: (value) => ({
          style: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center",
            whiteSpace: "nowrap",
          },
        }),
        setCellProps: (value) => ({
          style: {
            textAlign: "center",
          },
        }),
      },
    },
    {
      name: "pilierE",
      options: {
        empty: false,
        download: true,
        filter: false,
        sort: false,
        display: false,
        viewColumns: false,
      },
    },
  ];
```

and this is the onDownload function :

```
onDownload: (buildHead, buildBody, columns, rows) => {
  console.log(columns);
  const all = [];
  if (selectedRows.length) {
    selectedRows.forEach((row, index) => {
      let object = {
        index: index,
        data: row,
      };
      console.log("OBJ");
      all.push(object);
    });
    return "\uFEFF" + buildHead(columns) + buildBody(all);
  } else {
    setOpenExportAlert(true);
    return false;
  }
},
```

So, i'm using  `download: true,` and  `display: false,`  to hide show column and to enable , disable download .

Currently i'm getting this error :

```
> utils.js:91 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
>     (reading 'download')
>     at utils.js:91:1
>     at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
>     at utils.js:87:1
>     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
>     at i (utils.js:84:1)
>     at Object.onDownload (Home.js:342:1)
>     at buildCSV (utils.js:105:1)
>     at createCSVDownload (utils.js:130:1)
>     at TableToolbar.js:193:1
>     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
```

How can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

```
I fix the problem, i have filterOptions like this , so i set useDisplayedColumnsOnly and useDisplayedRowsOnly to true instead of false

  downloadOptions: {
          filename: "IIG-EXPORT.csv",
          separator: ";",
          filterOptions: {
            useDisplayedColumnsOnly: false, // it was true
            useDisplayedRowsOnly: false, // it was true
          },
        },
```